# Django undirected graph

Tags: django, django-models, graph

I want to build an undirected graph in Django.  I have built an edge model with two foreign keys (first,second) to the node class, but there is a conflict with the related_name.  I can use first_set and second_set, but since the graph is undirected, it doesn't matter if it is being liked to or from.  What is the recommended way to deal with this scenario?

Edit: Here are roughly the models I'm working with:

```
class Node(models.Model):
    #some irrelevant stuff

class Edge(models.Model):
    #some other stuff
    first = models.ForeignKey('Node',related_name=None)
    second = models.ForeignKey('Node',related_name=None)
```

What I would like to have is `some_node.connected_nodes_set` be something to the effect of a RelatedManager, similar to what would have been setup for either the first_set or second_set had I used related_names, except that it would have all of the nodes that can be reached with a single edge, instead of just those which can be reached in one direction.

Comment: Can you post your edge and node models?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had to do something similar with my current project.  My solution was to have a `ManyToManyField` in my equivalent to your `Node` model.  Something like this:

```
class Node(models.Model):
    adjacent = models.ManyToManyField("self", null=True, blank=True)
```

Note that the ["self"](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#recursive-relationships) above is necessary to allow the `ManyToManyField` to point back to itself.

Using this code, all nodes adjacent to a given node `N` can be found using `N.adjacent.all()`.

Comment: This looks promising, but the problem is that I need some extra data in the edge model.  At first thought, it would seem that I could use a ManyToManyField("self",through="Edge",symmetrical=True), but the documentation specifically says that you must use symmetrical=False if you are using a through model.

Comment: You'll have to make sure that the inverse relationship is created every time you make an `Edge`, then.  Off of the top of my head, that should be possible to do automatically by overriding `Edge`'s `save` method.

Comment: The problem with that though Jeff, is that this is not an undirected graph if your doing it both ways but a directed graph with a pair of to-and-from links. Whilst its practical in one sense, it has a lot of unintended topological consequences. Regardless, it just doesn't seem that django supports it natively. It might however be possible to put the M2M relation via another model and throw a bit of logic into the model to recreate the desired relationship. Not a totally valid answer, but such is life.